# Concurrent Session Control and custom authentication

Tags: spring-security

I have a problem i.e. to avoid using `/j_security_check` and yet able to control the number of concurrent session.

I have followed this thread:

[Spring concurrent session control not working, user can login multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062585/spring-concurrent-session-control-not-working-user-can-login-multiple-times)

One of the solution (that I know of) is to invoke 
`ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy.onAuthentication()` but this is deprecated since spring security 3.2 . So what is the alternative for this. 
Hopefully I will find an answer for this here

Comment: use `ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy` instead as explained in javadoc of `ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy` (see http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RC1/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/session/ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy.html)

Comment: How do i get the instance of ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy and invoke that method.I am not sure if I know how to to that .

Comment: Sorry my bad I got it.I already have declared it in my spring application.xml file