# Customize Session Registry spring security

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security

I'm using spring security 3.1.4 and I'm trying to create a costume session registry that uses data base for saving open sessions.

I used this SessionRegistryImpl implementation as reference :https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/session/SessionRegistryImpl.java

This is my implementation:

```
@Component
public class ClusteredSessionRegistryImpl implements SessionRegistry, ApplicationListener<SessionDestroyedEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private PrincipalRepository principalRepository;

    @Autowired
    private SessionIdRepository sessionIdRepository;


    public List<Object> getAllPrincipals() {

    return new ArrayList<Object>(
                     this.principalRepository.findAllPrincipals());
    }


    public List<SessionInformation> getAllSessions(Object principal, boolean includeExpiredSessions) {

    final Set<String> sessionsUsedByPrincipal = this.principalRepository.findByPrincipal(
                                                 principal).getSessionsUsedByPrincipal();

    if (sessionsUsedByPrincipal == null) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    List<SessionInformation> list = new ArrayList<SessionInformation>(
                                      sessionsUsedByPrincipal.size());

    for (String sessionId : sessionsUsedByPrincipal) {
        SessionInformation sessionInformation = getSessionInformation(sessionId);

        if (sessionInformation == null) {
        continue;
        }

        if (includeExpiredSessions || !sessionInformation.isExpired()) {
        list.add(sessionInformation);
        }
    }

    return list;
    }


    public SessionInformation getSessionInformation(String sessionId) {

    Assert.hasText(
               sessionId,
               "SessionId required as per interface contract");
    SessionId sessionIdDoc = this.sessionIdRepository.findBySessionId(sessionId);

    if (sessionIdDoc == null)
        return null;

    return sessionIdDoc.getSessionInformation();
    }


    public void onApplicationEvent(SessionDestroyedEvent event) {

    String sessionId = event.getId();
    removeSessionInformation(sessionId);
    }


    public void refreshLastRequest(String sessionId) {

    Assert.hasText(
               sessionId,
               "SessionId required as per interface contract");

    SessionInformation info = getSessionInformation(sessionId);

    if (info != null) {
        info.refreshLastRequest();
    }
    }


    public void registerNewSession(String sessionId, Object principal) {

    Assert.hasText(
               sessionId,
               "SessionId required as per interface contract");
    Assert.notNull(
               principal,
               "Principal required as per interface contract");

    if (getSessionInformation(sessionId) != null) {
        removeSessionInformation(sessionId);
    }
    this.sessionIdRepository.save(new SessionId(
                            sessionId, new SessionInformation(
                                              principal, sessionId, new Date())));

    Principal principalDoc = this.putIfAbsent(principal);

    Set<String> sessionsUsedByPrincipal = principalDoc.getSessionsUsedByPrincipal();

    if (sessionsUsedByPrincipal == null) {
        sessionsUsedByPrincipal = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<String>();
    }

    sessionsUsedByPrincipal.add(sessionId);

    principalDoc.setSessionsUsedByPrincipal(sessionsUsedByPrincipal);

    this.principalRepository.save(principalDoc);

    }


    public void removeSessionInformation(String sessionId) {

    Assert.hasText(
               sessionId,
               "SessionId required as per interface contract");

    SessionInformation info = getSessionInformation(sessionId);

    if (info == null) {
        return;
    }

    SessionId sessionIdDoc = this.sessionIdRepository.findBySessionId(sessionId);
    if (sessionIdDoc == null) {
        return;
    }

    this.sessionIdRepository.delete(sessionIdDoc);

    Set<String> sessionsUsedByPrincipal = this.principalRepository.findByPrincipal(
                                               info.getPrincipal()).getSessionsUsedByPrincipal();

    if (sessionsUsedByPrincipal == null) {
        return;
    }

    sessionsUsedByPrincipal.remove(sessionId);

    if (sessionsUsedByPrincipal.isEmpty()) {

        Principal principalDoc = this.principalRepository.findByPrincipal(info.getPrincipal());

        this.principalRepository.delete(principalDoc);
    }
    else {

        Principal principalDoc = this.principalRepository.findByPrincipal(info.getPrincipal());

        principalDoc.setSessionsUsedByPrincipal(sessionsUsedByPrincipal);

        this.principalRepository.save(principalDoc);
    }

    }


    private Principal putIfAbsent(Object principal) {

    Principal principalDoc = this.principalRepository.findByPrincipal(principal);
    if (principalDoc == null) {
        return this.principalRepository.save(new Principal(
                                   principal, null));
    }
    else {
        return principalDoc;
    }

    }
}
```

my security xml:

```
    <security:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false"
        entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/player/login"
            access="permitAll" />

        <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"
            ref="twoFactorAuthenticationFilter" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
            access="isAuthenticated()" />


        <security:logout logout-url="/player/logout"
            success-handler-ref="playerLogoutSuccessHandler" />

        <security:session-management>
            <security:concurrency-control
                max-sessions="1" session-registry-ref="clusteredSessionRegistryImpl"
                error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
        </security:session-management>

    </security:http>

    <bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/demo/player/login" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="twoFactorAuthenticationFilter" class="com.xxx.filter.TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureHandler" />
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="playerAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
        <property name="postOnly" value="true" />
        <property name="extraParameter" value="domain" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="failureHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login?login_error=true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="bCryptPasswordEncoder"
        class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider
            ref="authenticationProvider">
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

The problam is it never enters the `public void registerNewSession(String sessionId, Object principal)`

so nothing is saved in the db.

EDIT:
I added a call to registerNewSession() from my authenticationSuccessHandler, is this a legitimate solution?

My new problem is that the max-sessions="1" doesn't work and I can open more then 1 session. (I override the equals and hash code of my principal)

Comment: This is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062585/spring-concurrent-session-control-not-working-user-can-login-multiple-times

Comment: Can we add custom session id